# Why Datagridview shows me just columns headers and not the rest of table?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I built and run my application correctly in the Visual Studio environment. Once I install, after publishing, everything works fine but datagridviews. They just display columns header without rest of table. Whats wrong with it? Did anyone experience it too?

Comment: Almost certainly there is an error connecting to the database but it is probably hidden by improper exception handling. Add some logging to your application, especially within `Catch` blocks. Nobody can give you a specific answer with the limited information provided.

Comment: What do you want me to do? Can you drive me doing it?

Comment: My car broke down. Has this ever happened to you? How do you fix it? ... See my point? I can't help you if you don't make an attempt to show the relevant information. Start with showing the code that loads the data. Does it have exception handling? Can you write to a log file when an error occurs ?

Comment: Here is my whole code. In this txt downloadable by wetransfer we.tl/t-o3AWgsPogx

Comment: I don't download code. The rules of SO state that you need [to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you're getting column headers, then your connection is right, you just aren't returning any rows from the query. Show us the code that populates the datasource of this datagridview.